# How to configure com.gluonhq.charm properly in Maven?

Tags: maven, gluon-mobile, openjfx, java-13

How do I have to configure this plugin? I tried this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
    <artifactId>charm</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>hello.HelloWorld</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But the plugin gets underlined red and isn't usable.

Greets
MatsG23

P.S.
I want to port this automatically created Gradle to an Maven, because I can get along better with this - want to add Packager for Windows

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.17'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'mats.app.NIMSpiel.Main'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.6'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        compileSdkVersion = '29'
    }
}
```

Comment: By plugin, you mean `client-maven-plugin`, don't you? Charm is a dependency, not a plugin. Start here: https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples and see HelloGluon sample.

Comment: I want to port this automatically created Gradle to an Maven... I'm not sure whats the general plugin is......

Comment: `jfxmobile` plugin is for Java 1.8, with Gradle. `Client-maven-plugin` is for Java 11+, with Maven. The link I posted above should get you started: add a pom like the one in HelloGluon, and start from there...